# Show that $EGH + BGC + HGC = \frac12 ABCD.$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, proof-explanation

[image]

I was not able to finish solving the exercise so I came to its solution but there is some part [yellow highlighted] is not possible to figure that out. How it is valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
$$EHC = EHB + CHB = \frac12 EDB + \frac 12 CDB = \frac12 EDC,$$
and
$$EHC = \color{blue}{EGH + BGC + HGC} + \color{red}{EBG} = EGH + BGC + HGC + \color{red}{\frac 12 EAB}.$$
From the two equations,

$$ \color{blue}{EGH + BGC + HGC}  = \frac12 EDC - \color{red}{\frac 12 EAB} =\frac12 ABCD.$$